is there a limit to how deep Hugo checks for md files in the content directory?
I'm trying to generated static sites with Hugo so I can just write markdown for the content. I'm using the site as a notes sort of thing while learning javascript/typescript so that I can look at the content directory of and see my typescript code that I want to run client side on google chrome.
I've configured a vanilla-ts vite template in the same directory as my hugo project and I want hugo to build into vite's src directory so that i can live server from vite's dev mode and publish with vite too, basically I trully just need a Markdown to html honestly.
I'm trying out Hugo for this problem. But for some reason I think there's a limit to how deep hugo's file watcher is because even though I've tried many different configurations, it just won't render html from some of my markdown
this is current directory structure
.
├── .eslintignore
├── .eslintrc.cjs
├── .gitignore
├── .hugo_build.lock
├── .prettierignore
├── .prettierrc.cjs
├── archetypes
│   └── default.md
├── content
│   ├── _index.md
│   ├── chaptersections
│   │   ├── section1
│   │   │   └── recursion-and-stack
│   │   │       ├── index.md
│   │   │       ├── main.ts
│   │   │       └── tasks
│   │   │           └── task1
│   │   │               └── sum-to
│   │   │                   ├── index.md
│   │   │                   └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section2
│   │   │   └── rest-params-and-spread
│   │   │       ├── index.md
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section3
│   │   │   └── variable-scope-closure
│   │   │       ├── index.md
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section5
│   │   │   └── global-object
│   │   │       ├── index.md
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section6
│   │   │   └── function-object
│   │   │       ├── index.md
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section8
│   │   │   └── set-timeout-interval
│   │   │       ├── index.md
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   └── section9
│   │       └── decorators-and-forwarding
│   │           ├── index.md
│   │           └── main.ts
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── public
│   │   └── sword.svg
│   ├── reset.css
│   └── style.css
├── hugo.toml
├── layouts
│   ├── _default
│   │   └── single.html
│   ├── index.html
│   └── partials
│       └── sectionList.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── categories
│   │   └── index.xml
│   ├── chaptersections
│   │   ├── index.xml
│   │   ├── section1
│   │   │   └── recursion-and-stack
│   │   │       ├── index.html
│   │   │       ├── main.ts
│   │   │       └── tasks
│   │   │           └── task1
│   │   │               └── sum-to
│   │   │                   └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section2
│   │   │   └── rest-params-and-spread
│   │   │       ├── index.html
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section3
│   │   │   └── variable-scope-closure
│   │   │       ├── index.html
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section5
│   │   │   └── global-object
│   │   │       ├── index.html
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section6
│   │   │   └── function-object
│   │   │       ├── index.html
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   ├── section8
│   │   │   └── set-timeout-interval
│   │   │       ├── index.html
│   │   │       └── main.ts
│   │   └── section9
│   │       └── decorators-and-forwarding
│   │           ├── index.html
│   │           └── main.ts
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.xml
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── public
│   │   └── sword.svg
│   ├── reset.css
│   ├── sitemap.xml
│   ├── style.css
│   └── tags
│       └── index.xml
├── tsconfig.json
└── vite.config.ts

47 directories, 61 files


Build output from hugo is in the same directory named src
As you can see it has built htmls with the correct layouts and rendering with those section pages, I start adding tasks and it is unable to render that one.
I don't know what else to do i tried a bunch of different configurations. I don't know why it doesn't do that one task md file
this is my current hugo.toml
baseURL = 'https://example.org/'
languageCode = 'en-us'
title = 'Chapter 6: Functions'
publishDir = "src"
contentDir = "content"


There is no limitation in content depth, as explained in the Hugo documentation:

The sections can be nested as deeply as you want. The important thing
to understand is that to make the section tree fully navigational, at
least the lower-most section must include a content file. (i.e.
_index.md).

When I faced such an issue, i was adding an _index.md file to help Hugo detect the missing branch.
